# Can the permissions of files in vboxfs use the real permissions instead of all 770?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, permissions, file-permissions

I have a VirtualBox VM (Guest) and I share a folder tree via the vboxfs mechanism. The original folder tree is on my main computer (Host). It worked great except for the permissions.

When I check files on the Host, the permissions are set to 644 or 664 for files, and 755 or 775 for folders. But when I look at the permissions on the Guest, it all looks like 770.

Is there a way to change that and get the real permissions in the Guest?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could enter my own `/etc/fstab` entry like so:

```
sharename /home/alexis/shared-folder vboxsf uid=1000,gid=1000,nodev 0 0
```

and that will do exactly what I expect: it keeps the permissions as found in my Host folders.

I have to test a few things, `sharename` is probably what you want to define in the Transient Shared Folder.

The `/home/alexis/shared-folder` path is your folder on your VM. You can, of course, use any path you'd like.

The `vboxsf` is the VirtualBox File System. I guess we already know that.

Next we have a list of options:

- `uid=1000` -- use 1,000 as the user identifier for files linked in this way; you can find the user identifiers in `/etc/passwd`. It is likely 1,000 if you want to use your own default user since the first user created is assign that UID.
- `gid=1000` -- like the `uid`, but for the group; you can find the group identifiers in `/etc/group`.
- `nodev` -- ignore device files on that file system.

[Other options are available](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/mount.vboxsf.8.html) if you would like to make additional changes.

I happen to have `uid` and `gid` defined as the same (1000/1000) on my Host computer, but that should not matter here.

I still need to reboot to see how it behaves on a reboot. For sure, I just `umount`-ed and re-`mount`-ed in a console, so you can always fix your folder that way. (I'll put more info once I tested this feature across reboots.)

```
sudo umount /home/alexis/shared-folder
sudo mount sharename
```

The `mount` command shown above assumes you added your shared folder info on your VM computer.

Specifically, about the permissions, the `dmode` and `fmode` options can be used to change the mode of the file to, for example, 660 and 770. Not setting those options is what causes the permissions to *flow through*.